# What does enable sync do when uploading feature layer from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, feature-layer

Whenever I upload a feature layer from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online (AGOL), I see this option:

[image]

I want to know what this option means.

Does it mean there is a live connection between the feature layer in Pro and the uploaded layher in AGOL?

Answer (score 1):

The activation of this option lets you work with a local copy of the data, even while they are offline, and synchronize changes when you are connected again.

Comment: BeaR is correct.  It is important to note that these sync operations are very important to some of the mobile applications like Survey123 and ArcGIS Collector.  If you want users to be able to load data into these apps on a tablet or phone, work with the data, and then submit their edits back into the ArcGIS Online environment, then you need to turn on the Sync option.

Comment: Very clear! However what is the relationship with Arcgis Online then ?